# What is more probable? Six $6$-sided dice landing in combinations

Tags: probability, dice

I am having trouble with compound probability.

What is more probable, six $6$-sided dice landing in the combination of $111111$ or the same amount of $6$-sided dice landing in the combination of $532416$?

Intuitively, I think that compound probability should take place here, but it also seems that considering the order, these combinations of dice are single units that each have equal chance to happen after a dice throw.

Thank you,

M.

Comment: If order matters, probability is equal.

Comment: Correct on your latter intuition: in order, 111111 is just as likely the outcome of 6 successive throws as 532416

Comment: I will emphasize that the outcome "*One of each face is shown*" which would include outcomes such as 123456, 135246, 532416, etc... is different than "*The exact sequence 532416 occurs in that order*".  The probability that one of each face is shown is indeed much higher (*by a factor of $6!$*) than the probability that every die showed a $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have the same probability. Fix any sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6$ of $6$ possible outcomes of a die cast, and the probability of getting that sequence will be $\frac1{6^6}$.